# How to update only one field in mongodb through angular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

```
$http.put('/api/datas/' + val[$rootScope.id]._id,val[$rootScope.id].values[0].quantity=$scope.aqw);
```

this is returning "bad request error".Can anyone point me in the right direction.?

Comment: its a server side issue, this isnt going to help.

Comment: @SaneeshB right. It's a server side issue. I don't know if is NodeJs or otherwise but for update one single field in a mongodb document you should use `update` with `$set` object.